# pip executes the wrong python library versions inside virtual env

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-mavericks, virtualenvwrapper

I create a virtual enviroment with `virtualenvwrapper` and then I try to install django in it with `pip`. However I keep getting an error due to a conflict in python versions.

```
$ mkvirtualenv env
$ workon env
$ pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1085, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 201, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 554, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, cache=self.cache)
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 671, in get_page
    resp = urlopen(url)
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 176, in __call__
    response = self.get_opener(scheme=scheme).open(url)
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 238, in get_opener
    headers.append(("User-agent", build_user_agent()))
  File "/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 35, in build_user_agent
    _implementation = platform.python_implementation()
  File "/Users/mingot/soft/anaconda/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1486, in python_implementation
    return _sys_version()[0]
  File "/Users/mingot/soft/anaconda/lib/python2.7/platform.py", line 1451, in _sys_version
    repr(sys_version))
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]'
```

In the system, I am running python anaconda:

```
$ python 
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 24 2013, 07:02:20) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
```

and the `$PATH` is set to

```
/Users/mingot/soft/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

while inside the virtual enviroment, the python version is:

```
(env)$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
```

and the `$PATH`:

```
/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/bin:/Users/mingot/soft/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

I understand that the problem is that inside the virtual enviroment, while executing the non anaconda python 2.7.5, it is still using `platforms.py` from anaconda library, causing the crash in the evaluation of the regex as suggested [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/33). I do not care which python version to use inside the virtual enviroment. Any suggestion on how to tell the python of inside the virtual enviroment the correct `platforms.py` to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on a Mac with Anaconda installed.  The way I fixed it was searching for platform.py, then modifying the following (commenting out a line):

**ORIGINAL**

```
_sys_version_parser = re.compile(
    r'([\w.+]+)\s*'
    '\|[^|]*\|\s*' # version extra
    '\(#?([^,]+),\s*([\w ]+),\s*([\w :]+)\)\s*'
    '\[([^\]]+)\]?')
```

**CHANGE TO**

```
_sys_version_parser = re.compile(
    r'([\w.+]+)\s*'
    #'\|[^|]*\|\s*' # version extra # Just comment this line out
    '\(#?([^,]+),\s*([\w ]+),\s*([\w :]+)\)\s*'
    '\[([^\]]+)\]?')
```

This is with virtualenv==1.10.1 and anaconda 1.9.2

Comment: Thanks Will, I end up doing the same as well!

Answer (score 3):

The solution I end up doing is creating a symbolic link to `platforms.py` inside the virtual enviroment library folder from the library file of the correct python version.

```
$ pwd
/Users/mingot/virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7
$ ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.py platform.py
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I worked out was to supplement `virtualenv.py` so it not only copies over the Python binary to the new environment, but also the accompanying `libpythonX.Y.so` shared library files. Without them, the tiny Anaconda Python binary (take a look at it — it is only a few kilobytes in size) links against the system libpython instead of the Anaconda libpython and so you have the system Python’s version string getting parsed by Anaconda's mutant `platform.py` code.

Here is a short shell script that will fix `virtualenv.py`; run it once you have your Anaconda environment activated and have run `pip install virtualenv` to make the `virtualenv` tool available inside of it:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/homedir/blob/master/bin/%2Cfix-virtualenv-for-anaconda